# Swift Realm "Property has been made optional" error

Tags: swift, database, realm

So I use Realm to store data about favorite things that a user chose, for the model itself, it's required to be optional for some of the properties, but when I tried to open Realm, it gave me an error like this:
[image: Error]

Here's the FavoriteModel:
[image]

And here's the viewmodel where I open the Realm:
[image]

I've searched for answers, but it seems like there's nothing wrong with define the optional properties like that from the forums, anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's very important that code and errors are included as text in the question, not screenshots or links. Include code and structures as text so we can use them in answers with copy/paste. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Also, Images and links are not searchable so they may not be located by future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Migrations are required if you make a complex change to an object such as renaming a property or in your case, changing a fields type from not optional to optional.

A migration is *not* required if a property is added or deleted as that's handled automatically as long as you increment the schemaVersion.

The migration process, description and code examples is fully covered in the Realm Getting Started Guide [Change an Object Model - Swift SDK](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/change-an-object-model/?_ga=2.24604412.758228516.1668088609-762773769.1656853287)

In detail, from the guide

> For more complex schema updates, you must also manually specify the
> migration logic in a migrationBlock. This might include changes such
> as:
>
> Adding required properties that must be populated with default values
>
> Combining fields
>
> Renaming a field
>
> Changing a field's type
>
> Converting from an object to an embedded object

Keeping in mind that migrations only apply to Local Realms and do NOT apply to Synced Realms.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Jay said, when you make any change to properties in your Realm you should change the migration code too. You can do something like this, for example:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift
import Realm

@main
/// The app starting point
struct AppMain: SwiftUI.App {
    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    init() {
        let config = RLMRealmConfiguration.default()
        config.schemaVersion = 38 // <--- Increase this number!
        config.migrationBlock = { (migration, oldSchemaVersion) in
            // nothing to do
        }
        RLMRealmConfiguration.setDefault(config)
        _ = try! Realm()
    }
    
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            AppView()
        }
    }
    
    
}
```